# C# generics - generic interface conversion error

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following interfaces, I don't understand why the second method defined on `ITransactionConsumer` will not compile. The compiler complains that it is not convertable to `ITransaction<IUser>` - but there is a generic constraint that `TUser` *is* an `IUser`..?

```
    public interface ITransactionConsumer
    {
        //fine
        PaymentSession<TTransaction> ConsumeTransaction<TTransaction>( TTransaction transaction ) 
            where TTransaction : ITransaction<IUser>;

        //compile error - TTransaction is not convertable to ITransaction<IUser>
        PaymentSession<TTransaction> ConsumeTransactionWithTUser<TTransaction, TUser>(TTransaction transaction) 
            where TTransaction : ITransaction<TUser> where TUser : IUser;
    }

    public class PaymentSession<TTransaction>
        where TTransaction : ITransaction<IUser>
    {
    }

    public interface ITransaction<out TUser>
        where TUser : IUser
    {
        TUser User { get; }
        string Id { get; }
    }

    public interface IUser
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you need to add a class constraint to `TUser`, i.e. `where TUser class, IUser`.

Comment: I get a different compile error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0314 The type 'TTransaction' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTransaction' in the generic type or method 'PaymentSession<TTransaction>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TTransaction' to 'ITransaction<IUser>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you replace your offending line with this?

```
  PaymentSession<TTransaction> ConsumeTransactionWithTUser<TTransaction, TUser>(TTransaction transaction)
     where TTransaction : ITransaction<TUser>, ITransaction<IUser> where TUser : IUser;
```

**Edit:**
Since that worked, the most correct approach (for what I expect you intended with your code) would be to use the syntax you used in your first **ConsumeTransaction** declaration:

```
  PaymentSession<TTransaction> ConsumeTransactionWithTUser<TTransaction, TUser>(TTransaction transaction)
     where TTransaction : ITransaction<IUser>;
```

The mistake you made involves your **PaymentSession** return value. Your **PaymentSession** class expresses a constraint on the type argument it can accept. You defined that type argument as **TTransaction** and then specified that **TTransaction** must implement an interface **ITransaction** that has **IUser** as its type parameter. But you then tried to declare a function **ConsumeTransactionWithTUser** that returns a type of **PaymentSession** where **TTransaction** is a type that implements **IUser**. A type that implements an interface is not the same as the interface itself! **PaymentSession**'s type must be **IUser**--that is the constraint you specified, which is why the compiler complained: **ITransaction< TUser >** is not the same as **ITransaction< IUser >**.

To wrap up: Your constraint in the **PaymentSession** class requires the generic type to be of type **ITransaction < IUser >**--that's more restrictive than saying that **PaymentSession** requires the generic type to be of generic type **ITransaction** that accepts a type that implements **IUser**.

Comment: That works! Still a little confused as to why that's necessary but that's what I need. Thank you, will mark as correct.

Comment: A good answer should include explanation as well as code. Otherwise nobody learns anything.

Comment: Working on explanation--will provide at next break.